# Afterglow Xbox 360 Controller no longer works on PC?

Tags: technical-issues, pc, controllers

I recently got an Afterglow Xbox 360 controller for use on my PC. Worked fine for a few weeks. Leave it overnight. Go to work. Come back. Controller doesn't work. Fidget around with it. None of the buttons work. It still lights up and the Xbox LED is still working but none of the buttons work.

Before you give me the usual suggestion of ''installing drivers'' and ''Checking if its plugged correctly''. Trust me. I have done all this, and this controller required no drivers in the first place. I was playing need for speed last night with it just fine. Would any of you have any idea what to attempt before I simply rip it open?

Comment: What OS? Can you check whether the device appears in the Game Controllers panel? or under 'Devices and Printers? I had to [manually tell Windows which driver to use](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/282826/28182) because windows didn't recognise it as an 'Xbox' controller.

Comment: The device does not appear anywhere. OS is windows 10

Comment: Hmmm, not even in Device Manager? It might be under 'Unknown' or 'Unspecified Device' headings...

Comment: In case the user is still around - The Xbox LEDs, was the entire circle glowing/blinking on the center or just one of the slices?