# How do I fix my Xbox 360 controller?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, hardware

I have a wired 360 controller. It doesn't have any breakaway parts in the cord.
Here are the problems:

- The lights won't turn on,
- It's unresponsive,
- The little motor in it that does the vibration keeps running,
- It won't show up in the device management panel,
- I even opened it up to see if any of the components were damaged but none of them are.

Does any of you guys know how I can fix it?

Comment: What brand is the controller? What devices have you tried it on? It sounds like you're connecting it to PC - does it work on the Xbox 360? Have you got the [correct drivers installed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/282826/28182) on your PC?